# 'Always on top' window on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, desktop, window-manager, ventura, textedit

I need some way to place any chosen window to always be on top.

For example, when I use TextEdit I sometimes need to write something from Google and I have to split the screen or click to open TextEdit to start writing and then when I go to change tabs it disappears. Or also on Google, because sometimes I need to use two tabs at the same time for two different things. I want an app or a code that I can use a command to activate the Window or not.

On the Windows system, there is an application called Microsoft Powertoys that allows you to do this with any window and for free.

I already tried to install Afloat but I couldn't.

Comment: There is no Windows application called Powertoys.  It’s a collection of utilities and the utility in question is called *Always on Top.”